# Foreach not applicable on tweets

Tags: android, twitter, twitter-fabric

I am trying to get tweets using **Fabric**. I uploaded a sample code from the website and tried to see what happens.

```
final List<Long> tweetIds = Arrays.asList(510908133917487104L, 829245714509225984L);
    TweetUtils.loadTweets(tweetIds, new Callback<Tweet>() {
        @Override
        public void success (Result<Tweet> result) {
            for (Tweet tweet : result.data) {
                myLayout.addView(new TweetView(MainActivity.this, tweet));
            }

        }

        @Override
        public void failure (TwitterException exception) {
            // Toast.makeText(...).show();
        }
    });
```

Its giving me an error at the for statement in success block

> foreach not applicable to type 'com.twitter.sdk.android.core.models.Tweet'

The result.data is of tweet type too.
Am i using the for loop the wrong way or is it something else?

Comment: Try for (Tweet tweet : tweetIds)

Comment: I tried that but those are mismatching types. tweetIds is List<Long> while tweet is a tweet type.

Comment: You are not getting the correct types....try final List<Tweet> tweetIds = Arrays.asList(510908133917487104L, 829245714509225984L);

Comment: `Result<Tweet> result` is a single tweet, not a list of tweets. You can't iterate through single object.

Comment: Sorry, i am not able to get it, could you please explain how i can iterate through a list of tweets and display them in my layout

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end, I iterated only through the `tweetids` list and displayed them individually

```
    final LinearLayout myLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.layoutTwitter);
    final List<Long> tweetIds = Arrays.asList(510908133917487104L, 829245714509225984L, 829253590753636353L);
    for (Long longvar : tweetIds) {
        TweetUtils.loadTweet(longvar, new Callback<Tweet>() {
            @Override
            public void success (Result<Tweet> result) {
                CompactTweetView compactTweetView = new CompactTweetView(MainActivity.this, result.data);
                myLayout.addView(compactTweetView);
            }

            @Override
            public void failure (TwitterException exception) {

            }
        });
    }
```